# What is the benefit of using `in` operators in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Sometimes I see the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)s on JavaScript code on the web, but not so many times.
Just few code used it.

I guess the reason why use it is to make the code more semantic.
I'm curious about it now.

What was the purpose when they standardize it?
What is the benefit of using `in` operators in JavaScript?

Edit:
Umm, I'm sorry. I was thinking of `.` operator, so what I wanted to say was..

"You can use these instead to check if the property exists, then why you use `in`?"

```
if(object["name"])
if(object.name)
```

I couldn't think of the case that the `object` is `{name: undefined}`. Sorry.

Comment: Benefits as opposed to what?

Comment: Just like any other operator, you use it when you need to do or find out what it does or finds out for you.

Comment: @Joaquinglez — What array? What does this have to do with `for`?

Comment: @Quentin as opposed to `.`...  I just..

Comment: @SwiftArchitect I'm new in Stack Overflow. I'm so sorry.. I've clarified it.

Comment: No problem: just reformat your question using the advice provided in the comments, remove much of these comments, and the question may get more traction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `in` operator makes it possible to see whether an object has a property with a particular name.

```
if ("name" in object) { ... }
```

Without `in`, that would be harder. You can test for `null` or `undefined`, but that doesn't answer the question unambiguously.

Note that the token `in` also appears in the `for ... in` loop:

```
for (name in object)
```

That's the same word `in` of course, but in that situation it is not acting as an expression operator; it's just there as sugar for the syntax.

Comment: Can't I use `if(object.name)` or `if(object["name"])` instead of it?

Comment: If `object.name` is the empty string, or zero, or `NaN`, or `false`, or `null`, or `undefined`, then the test `if (object.name)` will fail in exactly the same way as if `name` was not a property of the object.

Comment: Ah, I see.. `{name: undefined}`..

Comment: Yes, exactly. The `in` operator is the quickest way to see if the property really is present on the object.

Comment: It seems I asked a stupid question.. and that would be the reason why I got 10 downvotes..

Comment: @K._ I do not think your question deserved 10 downvotes :)

Comment: There is a second use of `in` that you didn't cover and that is `for ( variable in object )` ... which iterates through all the properties in object.

Comment: @JohnHascall that is another use of the token `in`, but it is not `in` as an expression operator. It's part of the syntax but it's not an "operator" in that situation. It's like the difference between the comma operator and commas that separate function arguments: same token, different semantics.

Comment: Given the mentions in the question comments about `array` and `for`, I'm thinking that's a distinction lost to the questioner.